# The Chronology of Games sorted by story events

Tags: kingdom-hearts

After the new announced games and several remakes and mixes out there I'm interested in the chronology order of the Kingdom Hearts story. Can anyone tell me the whole(so far) Kingdom Hearts chronology sorted by story events?

Comment: @Frank seems like you're right. Is it better to edit the accepted answer on the other question to make it up to date or should i just add my own answer there?

Comment: I'd recommend adding your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

### Kingdom Hearts Chronology

---

#### Sorted by story events

1. [Kingdom Hearts X](http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/Kingdom_Hearts_%CF%87)

   > Kingdom Hearts X (chi) is a Kingdom Hearts game that is exclusive to
   >   PC browsers. The game is free to play, but includes additional
   >   purchasable items.
   >   The game is re-released as Kingdom Hearts Unchained χ in Japan on September 3rd, 2015.

[image: Kingdom Hearts X Logo]

2. [Kingdom Hearts Birth by Sleep](http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/Kingdom_Hearts_Birth_by_Sleep)

   > Kingdom Hearts Birth by Sleep is a Kingdom Hearts prequel for the Sony
   >   Playstation Portable (PSP). It was released in Japan on January 9,
   >   2010, September 7, 2010 in North America, and September 10, 2010 in
   >   Europe

[image: Kingdom Hearts Birth by Sleep Logo]

3. [Kingdom Hearts](http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/Kingdom_Hearts_(game))

   > Kingdom Hearts is the first game in the Kingdom Hearts series directed
   >   by Tetsuya Nomura. Revolving around a fourteen-year old boy named
   >   Sora, it details his adventures after his homeworld is destroyed by
   >   sinister creatures known as the Heartless, and his attempts to restore
   >   his world and reunite with his friends.

[image: Kingdom Hearts Logo]

4. [Kingdom Hearts 358/2 Days](http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/Kingdom_Hearts_358/2_Days) **begins during events at the end of Kingdom Hearts**

   > Kingdom Hearts 358/2 Days (read "Kingdom Hearts Three-Five-Eight Days
   >   over Two") is an RPG developed by Square Enix for the Nintendo DS,
   >   with aid from h.a.n.d. It focuses on the life of Roxas between the end
   >   of Kingdom Hearts and the beginning of Kingdom Hearts II, exploring
   >   the time from Roxas's creation until his confrontation with Riku that
   >   leads to his placement in the Simulated Twilight Town.

[image: Kingdom Hearts 358/2 Days Logo]

5. [Kingdom Hearts: Chain of Memories](http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/Kingdom_Hearts:_Chain_of_Memories)

   > Kingdom Hearts: Chain of Memories is a Game Boy Advance sequel to
   >   Kingdom Hearts. It was published by Square Enix and developed by
   >   Jupiter, and was released in 2004.
   >
   > - **Kingdom Hearts 358/2 Days** runs **concurrently** with events of Kingdom
   >     Hearts: Chain of Memories **but ends later**.

[image: Kingdom Hearts: Chain of Memories Logo]

6. [Kingdom Hearts II](http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/Kingdom_Hearts_II)

   > Kingdom Hearts II is the sequel to Kingdom Hearts and Kingdom Hearts:
   >   Chain of Memories, and like the two previous games, focuses on Sora
   >   and his friends' continued battle against the Darkness. It also offers
   >   a number of improvements over the original with many new features,
   >   most notably Sora's Drive Form function, an improved camera, and
   >   in-battle options called Reaction Commands.

[image: Kingdom Hearts 2 Logo]

7. [Kingdom Hearts coded](http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/Kingdom_Hearts_coded)

   > Kingdom Hearts coded is a game in the Kingdom Hearts series that was
   >   released on the mobile phone as a puzzle game using 3D backgrounds. It
   >   focuses on King Mickey and Sora, depicting the events that transpired
   >   prior to the end of Kingdom Hearts II; the game is also deeply linked
   >   with Kingdom Hearts Birth by Sleep.

[image: Kingdom Hearts coded Logo]

8. [Kingdom Hearts 3D: Dream Drop Distance](http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/Kingdom_Hearts_3D:_Dream_Drop_Distance)

   > Kingdom Hearts 3D: Dream Drop Distance (previously known as Kingdom
   >   Hearts 3D) is a game in the Kingdom Hearts series released on the
   >   Nintendo 3DS hand-held system. It was released on March 29, 2012 in
   >   Japan, July 31, 2012 in US and Canada, July 20, 2012 in Europe, and
   >   July 26th in Australia.

[image: Kingdom Hearts 3D Logo]

9. [Kingdom Hearts III](http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/Kingdom_Hearts_III)

   > One of the next installments in the Kingdom Hearts series is currently
   >   called Kingdom Hearts III. It was officially revealed at E3 2013 via a
   >   trailer, alongside the announcement it would be released for the
   >   PlayStation 4 and the Xbox One.

[image: Kingdom Hearts 3 Logo]

### Remakes

1. [Kingdom Hearts HD 1.5 ReMIX](http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/Kingdom_Hearts_-HD_1.5_ReMIX-)

   > Kingdom Hearts HD 1.5 ReMIX is an HD collection of two games
   >   from the Kingdom Hearts series. It features **Kingdom Hearts Final Mix**,
   >   **Kingdom Hearts Re:Chain of Memories**, and a full **cutscene collection**
   >   from **Kingdom Hearts: 358/2 Days** for Sony's PlayStation 3 platform.
   >   Both games have **remastered HD graphics** and Trophy support and the
   >   cutscenes from 358/2 Days have been remade in HD.

[image: Kingdom Hearts HD 1.5 Logo]

2. [Kingdom Hearts HD 2.5 ReMIX](http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/Kingdom_Hearts_HD_2.5_ReMIX)

   > Kingdom Hearts HD 2.5 ReMIX is an HD remaster compilation of the
   >   Kingdom Hearts series and follow-up to Kingdom Hearts HD 1.5 ReMIX. It
   >   includes full HD remasters of Kingdom Hearts II Final Mix and Kingdom
   >   Hearts Birth by Sleep Final Mix. It also includes a collection of
   >   cutscenes from Kingdom Hearts Re:coded.

[image: Kingdom Hearts HD 2.5 Logo]

3. [Kingdom Hearts HD 2.8 Final Chapter Prologue](http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/Kingdom_Hearts_HD_2.8_Final_Chapter_Prologue)

   > Upcoming remake bundle including Kingdom Hearts 3D: Dream Drop
   >   Distance HD, Kingdom Hearts 0.2 Birth by Sleep -A Fragmentary
   >   Passage-, and the cutscenes for Kingdom Hearts X, titled as Kingdom
   >   Hearts X Back Cover. It will be released in Japan in 2016.

[image: Kingdom Hearts HD 2.8 Final Chapter Prologue Logo]